# How to italicize text using javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, khan-academy

Does anyone know how to italicize a strand of text using the text(); command?  I'm writing my code using Processing.JS (more specifically, on Khan Academy).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following command

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var result = str.italics();
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_italics.asp

Comment: Note: "*The italics() method is not standard*"

Comment: You should update your question that says your looking for a standard way.

Answer (score 0):

based on the [processing.js documentation](http://processingjs.org/reference/text_/), it looks like you can have italicized text based on the .ttf file you initialize it with. So just download an italic ttf font and do:

```
PFont font;
font = loadFont("italic-webdings.ttf") // whatever the name of your italic ttf file is
textFont(font); 
String s = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
text(s, 15, 20, 70, 70);
```

Answer (score 0):

The KA way you can have 
    `textFont(createFont("brush script ms italic"));` which is the closest font for italicized.